# How to fix Error in Generating Report ' network failed' in ASP>NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code that generate report onload from Report Viewer. I have also a try catch exception but it doesn't catch any error. But main problem is 'it can generate a report but it is failed'. It says 'failed - network error'

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataSet dsWeeklyReportView = new DataSet();

                string ConnectionString = "";

                string FileName = "WeeklyReport" + ".xls";
                string extension;
                string encoding;
                string mimeType;
                string[] streams;
                Warning[] warnings;


                string Name = Session["ProjectName"].ToString();
                string Status = Session["ProjectStatus"].ToString();
                string Active = Session["ProjectActive"].ToString();

                ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("WEEKLYREPORTNAME", Session["ProjectName"].ToString()));
                paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("WEEKLYREPORTSTATUS", Session["ProjectStatus"].ToString()));
                paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("WEEKLYREPORTACTIVE", Session["ProjectActive"].ToString()));

                ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;

                ConnectionString = "DataSet";

                ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~") + "ReportGenerator.rdl";

                dsWeeklyReportView = oWeeklyReport.dsWeeklyReport(Name, Status, Active);
                dt = dsWeeklyReportView.Tables[0];
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(ConnectionString, dt));
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramList);
                ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
                // ReportViewer2.Visible = true;
                Byte[] mybytes = ReportViewer.LocalReport.Render("EXCEL", null,
                        out extension, out encoding,
                        out mimeType, out streams, out warnings); //for exporting to PDF  
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Server.MapPath("~//download//") + FileName))
                {
                    fs.Write(mybytes, 0, mybytes.Length);
                }

                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/xls";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
                Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/download/" + FileName));
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();
                Response.End();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
        }
    }
```

I already check parameters, path and names. There's no error in try catch and it generate a report but it is failed. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: What is the error ?
how you discover that error occurred send the details please

Comment: It generate report but it is failed 'failed - network error'  but there's no error catch in the code. Thank You

Comment: Try your code but remove Response.Close(); and Response.Clear() and let me know your feedback

Comment: Its working now! Thank you! This help a lot!

Comment: Congrats! just please take my solution below into consideration, you must not remove response.clear completely but you must call the correct function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found that calling `Response.End()` and `Response.Clear()`  its throwing exception always, the solution by calling :

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
```